# Why the embedding method of twitter does use a closure?

Tags: javascript, twitter, closures

In https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-timelines , twitter explain that to embed a timeline, you have to add these two line to you html :

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/twitterapi" data-widget-id="YOUR-WIDGET-ID-HERE">Tweets by @twitterapi</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

Why does the script use a closure instead of just doing it a more simple way ?

```
<script>var d=document,s="script",id="twitter-wjs";var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);};</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function scopes give you local variables.

Without the function, the parent page scope would be cluttered with symbols like `d`, `s`, `id`, `js`, `fjs`.

Maybe something else was using those.

Actually, this is not a closure, quite the opposite: A closure is a function that captures parts of its parent scope. They seem to be taking extra care *not* to do that, only referring to function parameters, not even to `document` from the parent scope.